# Is it possible to show a list of lists of strings in a listview?

Tags: wpf

I have a list of lists that are strings, like this:

```
List<List<string>>();
```

Each list has 2 elements, first one is a percent and the second one the value of the percent calculated from a value. Both are in string format and I would like to know if I can use this list of lists in a listview that shows two columns, one for the percent and the second one for the value.

I know that the other option it would be to create a class with two properties and create a list with this objects, but I would like to know if it is possible to avoid the need to create a new class only for this.

I am using MVVM pattern and I would like to avoid code behind too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an indexer in the Binding Path:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [0]}" Header="First"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [1]}" Header="Second"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```